# How to stop sticky div to overlap on footer?

Tags: jquery

I have copied the code from different blog to my fiddle account. Everything is working fine. When you scroll down the page, yellow bar stick on the page and when you reach scroll to the bottom, footer pushes the yellow bar up which is absolutely fine. But issue is, when I add text boxes more than 10 to 15 times by clicking the “Add” button, the yellow bar overlap the footer and text boxes goes below inside the browser window and not visible. I want footer to push the yellow sticky bar up even its height small or large. Anyone can help me to sort out the issue?

[Demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/k7xfc/](http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/k7xfc/)

**Jquery**

```
$window = $(window),
$sidebar = $(".sidebar"),
sidebarTop = $sidebar.position().top,
sidebarHeight = $sidebar.height(),
$footer = $(".footer"),
footerTop = $footer.position().top,    
$sidebar.addClass('fixed');

$window.scroll(function(event) {
scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
topPosition = Math.max(0, sidebarTop - scrollTop),
topPosition = Math.min(topPosition, (footerTop - scrollTop) - sidebarHeight);
$sidebar.css('top', topPosition);
});

$(document).ready(function () {
var counter = 2;
$("#addButton").click(function () {

        $('<div/>',{'id':'TextBoxDiv' + counter}).html(
          $('<label/>').html( 'Textbox #' + counter + ' : ' )
        )
        .append( $('<input type="text">').attr({'id':'textbox' + counter,'name':'textbox' + counter}) )
        .appendTo( '#TextBoxesGroup' )       
        counter++;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue preventing your expected result is that your code is utilizing the *initial* calculated sidebar height instead of getting the updated height during every scroll event.

```
$window.scroll(function (event) {
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var topPosition = Math.max(0, sidebarTop - scrollTop);

    // Ensure you are using the current sidebar height and not the initial height
    topPosition = Math.min(topPosition, (footerTop - scrollTop) - $sidebar.height());

    $sidebar.css('top', topPosition);
});
```

Another suggestion I would recommend is that you trigger the window scroll handler during the `addButton` click handler to ensure that you make the proper adjustments as you are adding items.

```
$("#addButton").click(function () {
    $('<div/>', {
        'id': 'TextBoxDiv' + counter
    }).html(
    $('<label/>').html('Textbox #' + counter + ' : '))
        .append($('<input type="text">').attr({
            'id': 'textbox' + counter,
            'name': 'textbox' + counter
    })).appendTo('#TextBoxesGroup');

    // Trigger the scroll handler to ensure the sidebar is properly positioned
    $window.triggerHandler('scroll');

    counter++;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SVzmz/1/)**

Comment: Ruben, Thanks for your suggestion. It looks great to me. I have to apply this functionality on ASP.NET project. I hope, there will be no more issues to implement this. Can I ping you back if I need further assistance on this?

Comment: @user1356607 Glad that helped. I would suggest creating a new question on SO if you find that you need more assistance. You'll have the added benefit of the rest of the community being able to help at that point. Once you do that, you can always reply here and leave a link to the new question so that I get notified.